# Python text adventure: How to make it so that when the player types specific keywords (in no particular order) certain text is displayed?

Tags: python, python-3.x, console, game-development

I'm writing a text adventure (also known as interactive story or choose your own adventure) using python. The idea is to make it so that players can type in whatever they want themselves to do in game (ex "punch window") into the console and then the console will display a response to that action ("the glass shatters but your fist is filled with splinters of glass").

To be more specific, I want to be able to make it so that if the player types the keywords 1) either throw or toss, 2) either rock or stone, 3) either smash or break or shatter, and 4) either glass or window into the console then the console says “you throw a rock at the window and the glass shatters” since that is what the player must be trying to do since they typed a combination of those keywords. Ideally, the order that the keywords are typed in doesn’t matter. For example the player could type “glass rock smash toss” and the game would still say “you throw a rock at the window and the glass shatters.” This is so that any sentence can be typed and lead to the solution (ex smashing the glass) as long as the sentence holds the correct meaning. How do I make this happen?

Also I have another (highly related) question. Let’s say that the player puts the right keywords in and so the game says “you throw a rock at the window and the glass shatters.”

How do I make it so that when the game says “you throw a rock at the window and the glass shatters” the following gets activated (basically meaning that it appears and influences the game as if it had “never existed” before):

> If the player types the keywords 1) either jump or go 2) either
> through or into or inside 3) either window or broken window or window
> frame then the console says "You jump through the broken window".

And how do I make it so that when the game says “you throw a rock at the window and the glass shatters” the following gets DEactivated (basically meaning that it gets “deleted” and does not influence the game anymore):

> If the player types the keywords 1) either jump or go 2) either
> through or into or inside 3) and 4) either window or broken window or
> window frame then the console says "You try to jump through the window
> and shatter the glass with your body but the window is too strong and
> you fall backwards".

I've tried googling and duckduckgoing about this to find answers with no luck. It feels impossible to find the right keywords.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your first question, here's a simple script that seems to do the kind of thing you're trying to do.

```
reqs = [
['throw', 'toss'],
['rock','stone'],
['smash','break','shatter'],
['glass','window']]

player_input = "glass throw stone break"

if all(any(s in player_input for s in syns) for syns in reqs):
    print("window broken")
else:
    print("window not broken")
```

The if statement tests whether at least one word from each "row" of `reqs` (i.e. each group of synonyms) appears in the input string. If the check returns true, then the window is broken. Otherwise, it isn't.

I don't understand what you're trying to get at with the second part of your question.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. I edited the second part of my question to make it more readable.